# Как изменить user agent в Watir  browser chrome

Tags: ruby, bash

Подсказите пожалуйста как менять Override the default HTTP Accept-Language header. в watir?

Answer (score 1):

Не получится так. Watir эмулирует браузер, а не HTTP запросы. Если нужно поменять установки браузера, такие как предпочитаемые языки, это делается [с помощью профилей](http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/), и зависит от используемого браузера. Например, [для Chrome](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc):

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['intl.accept_languages'] = "en"
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile
```

Comment: Вот какая ошибка получается
<code>
F, [2013-12-26T09:14:01.761905 #5634] FATAL -- : 
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: unrecognized chrome option: profile
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.7.236843,platform=Linux 3.2.0-56-generic x86_64)):
</code>

Comment: @Alexandru Какие версии gem'ов?